# Isotope v2 not laying out correctly after filtering

Tags: jquery-isotope

I'm using Metafizzy's Isotope to make an image gallery.  The layout mode is set to Masonry. http://www.davidbirn.com/.

There are 4 filter buttons:  All Items, Subset A, Subset B, Subset C.  Filtering is working correctly.

Layout works wonderfuly when going from "All" to one of the subsets, but it does not build a masonry layout if one goes from one of the Subsets to another.

Here is the JS code which drives Isotope. Seems like I need some sort of a layout refresh after the filter runs, but my understanding of JQuery is limited.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
//set Isotope options
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  percentPosition: true,
  layoutMode: 'masonry',
  masonry:{columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'},
  filter:'*',
});

// layout Isotope after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.isotope('layout');
});
});

// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
});

// filter items on button click
$('.filter-button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
$grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

I just had to move the //layout Isotope after each image loads// code to the end, after filtering.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).